# Android Listeners

Tags: java, android

Объясните пожалуйста начинающему смысл строки (2) данного кода
Чем подробней тем лучше, заранее благодарен :)

```
TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
display.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вешаем на `TextView` слушатель. Только зачем на `TextView` этот `listener`? Его нужно к `EditText`. 
`DigitsKeyListener`, согласно [официальной документации:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/DigitsKeyListener.html)

> Только для цифрового ввода
>
> Что же касается всех реализаций KeyListener , этот класс занимается
>   только аппаратной клавиатурой. Софт-клавиатура не обязательно будет вызывать
>   методы в этом классе.

`getInstance` - получаем объект данного класса.

Глянем на него:

```
private static final int SIGN = 1;
private static final int DECIMAL = 2;
public static DigitsKeyListener getInstance(boolean sign, boolean decimal) {
    int kind = (sign ? SIGN : 0) | (decimal ? DECIMAL : 0); //1

    if (sInstance[kind] != null)
         return sInstance[kind];

    sInstance[kind] = new DigitsKeyListener(sign, decimal); 
    return sInstance[kind];
}
```

Строчка с комментарием 1 - получаем номер, в случае `(true, true)` это 3.
Проверяем, не равен ли он `null` и если нет, то возвращаем его, если равен, то создаем новый объект и возвращаем его. Вкратцы все.

Answer (score 1):

`DigitsKeyListener` не дает вводить в текстовое поле что-то, кроме числа. Первое `true` разрешает отрицательные числа (первый знак может быть '-'). Второе `true` разрешает, чтобы число было десятичным (где-то среди цифр может быть одна '.').
Надежно работает только с аппаратной клавиатурой.